# Wordpress - Testing custom API endpoint with class dependency

Tags: php, unit-testing, wordpress-rest-api

Sorry I feel like really stuck here.

I have a plugin introducing a new Rest API controller (`WP_REST_Controller`) with basically a single endpoint which uses a separate class as a client to fetch some data. Let's say:

```
#my_plugin.php

function register_items_routes() {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_REST_My_Controller' ) ) {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/class-wp-my-controller.php';
    }

    $controller = new WP_REST_My_Controller();
    $controller->register_routes();
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_items_routes' );
```

_

```
#class-wp-my-controller.php

class WP_REST_My_Controller extends WP_REST_Controller {

/**
 * Registers the routes.
 */
public function register_routes() {
    $namespace = 'my/namespace';
    $path      = 'get-items';

    register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $path, [
        array(
            'methods'             => 'GET',
            'callback'            => array( $this, 'get_items' ),
            'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_items_permissions_check' )
        ),
    ] );
}

public function get_items_permissions_check( $request ) {
        return true;
}

/**
 * Get items from My_Class and return them.
 *
 * @param WP_REST_Request $request The incoming HTTP request.
 *
 * @return WP_REST_Response|WP_Error The response containing the items in JSON, WP_Error in case of error.
 */
public function get_items( $request ) {

    $client = new My_Class();

    try {
        $items = $client->fetch_some_items();
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        return new WP_Error(
        'some-client-error',
        $e->getMessage()
    );

    // Code to be tested. - Do some stuff with items and return.

    return new WP_REST_Response( $items );
}
```

How am I supposed to stub the `My_Class` dependency from PhpUnit in order to return a predefined set of items which I could test with?

```
public function test_get_items() {
    $request  = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/my/namespace/get-items' );
    $data = rest_get_server()->dispatch( $request );

    $expected_items = [
            'some_key1' => 'some_value1',
            'some_key2' => 'some_value2',
    ];
    
    $this->assertTrue( count($data['items']) == count($expected_items) );
}
```